# getting "Unhandled exception" error after applying canny edge detector using opencv /c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I get "Unhandled exception" error when I try to apply Canny edge detector into my image.

```
int width;
int height;
cv::Mat dis = Mat(width, height, CV_32FC1,Dis);
cv::Mat cannyEdge(dis.rows, dis.cols, CV_32FC1);
GaussianBlur( dis, dis, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );
Canny( dis, cannyEdge , 100 , 100 * 3, 3);
imshow("canny_edge",cannyEdge);
}
```

seems everything is correct, but I get error in Canny Function call line...

thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you creating `cv::Mat dis` when you're actually passing `distance` (which you don't even show us) as the input parameter to the `Canny` function? And I think you really shouldn't pass `dis` as input as well as output to `GaussianBlur`

Comment: I edited the post...it was by mistake...i changed it but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny) the parameter to the Canny() function

source image – single-channel 8-bit .
Desination   – same size and type as source.

And you are using 32 bit floating point image.

And try with

```
cv::Mat dis = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC1,Dis);
```

Comment: yes, I am using 32 bit floating points..is there any problem with that?

Comment: Yes canny() support only 8 bit single channel  image

Comment: so you mean, it must be CV_8U even if I am using floating points?

Comment: Thanks..I changed it and now I do not get that error. but why the window which I made for showing the edge detection is blinking?!!

Comment: it is strange, when I click on that it shows the result otherwise no!

Comment: I think Opencv doesn’t support 8 bit floating point image, so use CV_8UC1

Comment: @user3049356 when I click on that it shows the result otherwise no! – On what?.........

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42569/discussion-between-haris-and-user3049356)